# Swift - Editing a value of an item in a Codable Array

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have codable Dic of array

```
public struct Pattern: Codable {
    public let event: Event?
    public var parameterCurve: ParameterCurve?
    
    enum CodingKeys: CHHapticPattern.Key.RawValue, CodingKey {
        case event = "Event"
        case parameterCurve = "ParameterCurve"
    }
}

public struct ParameterCurve: Codable {
    public let parameterID: ParameterID?
    public let time: TimeInterval?
    public var parameterCurveControlPoints: [ParameterCurveControlPoint]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: CHHapticPattern.Key.RawValue, CodingKey {
        case parameterID = "ParameterID"
        case time = "Time"
        case parameterCurveControlPoints = "ParameterCurveControlPoints"
    }
}

public struct ParameterCurveControlPoint: Codable {
    public let time: TimeInterval?
    public var parameterValue: Float!
    
    enum CodingKeys: CHHapticPattern.Key.RawValue, CodingKey {
        case time = "Time"
        case parameterValue = "ParameterValue"
    }
}
```

i need to change the value of (ParameterCurveControlPoint.parameterValue)

```
 let parameter = appleHapticAudioPattern.pattern?.first(where: { $0.parameterCurve?.parameterCurveControlPoints != nil})?.parameterCurve?.parameterCurveControlPoints
    
    for i in parameter! {
        i.parameterValue += 0.2    // **_here this issue appear on xcode_**
    }
```

xcode alert me error like this:
 [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5sTt.png)

```
Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'i' is a 'let' constant
```

how can I solve this issue please?

Comment: Here you are using `struct`. Any `struct` object can't be mutated like this. You can describe your goal which can be achieved in another way.

Comment: Use `firstIndex(where:)` instead and update using that index, `parameterCurveControlPoints[index].parameterValue += 0.2`